# как соединить фронтэнд и бэкэенд?

Tags: веб-программирование, vue.js, django-rest-framework

Если django на бэке, а vue на фронте, то я просто по урлу через джанго отдаю index.hmtl с vue?
url в django тогда регуляркой задать чтоб всегда на index.hmtl попадал?
или это не правильный подход

Comment: django будет отдавать стартовую страницу с vue, а дальше rest. Т.е. все остальные адреса выдают данные, а vue строит на их основе интерфейс

Comment: @ArchDemon с урлами проблем не будет? то есть понятно если урл /home например отдает vue, а я захожу /home/product например, роутер vue уже заберет это?

Comment: Если вы делаете SPA приложение, то никаких реальных переходов не будет. Но если пользователь нажмёт F5, то можно получить ошибку 404. Чтобы такого не происходило, нужно либо настроить django на перенаправление всех запросов на index.html (за исключением реально существующих файлов), либо писать адреса роутинга vue в хэше адреса (через `#/home/product`)

Comment: @ArchDemon спасибо большое!